# Remplazar todos los caracteres inválidos para utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql, codificación

Remplazar todos los caracteres inválidos para utf8_general_ci?

Para hacer inserts sin problemas manteniendo el máximo de texto compatible (Caracteres Japoneses, rusos, acentos, caracteres especiales...) pero quitando todo lo no compatible.

Comment: ¿Cómo qué caracter sería inválido para UTF-8?

Comment: En tu editor de texto puedes guardar con encode y le das el que corresponde

Comment: ¿Existe un carácter no compatible? ¿O estás teniendo problemas a la hora de codificar a UTF?

Comment: he tenido problemas para guardar emojis en mysql con utf8 pero lo solucióne utilizando utf8mb4 en las tablas de mysql por que no conseguí hacerlo en php (Reemplazar los caracteres que no entran en UTF8)

Answer (score 0):

Especificar la configuración de caracteres por base de datos. Para crear una base de datos de tal manera que sus tablas a utilizar un conjunto de caracteres dada por defecto  y colación para almacenamiento de datos, utilice una **CREATE DATABASE** sentencia como esta:

```
CREAR DATABASE ejemplo
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Las tablas creadas en la base de datos a utilizar utf8 y utf8_general_ci por defecto para las columnas de caracteres.

Independientemente de cómo se configura el carácter de MySQL para el uso de la aplicación, también se debe tener en cuenta el entorno en el que dichas aplicaciones se ejecutan. Si se va a enviar declaraciones el uso de texto UTF-8, tomada desde un archivo que se crea en un editor, usted debe editar el archivo con la configuración regional de su entorno a UTF-8 para que la codificación del archivo es correcta y para que el sistema operativo maneja correctamente. Si se utiliza el mysql cliente desde una ventana de terminal, la ventana debe estar configurado para utilizar UTF-8 o caracteres no se muestre correctamente. Para una secuencia de comandos que se ejecuta en un entorno Web, el guión debe manejar adecuadamente la codificación de caracteres para su interacción con el servidor MySQL, y debe generar páginas que indican correctamente la codificación para que los navegadores saben cómo mostrar el contenido de las páginas. Por ejemplo, puede incluir esta etiqueta dentro de su elemento:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

¿Por que no usas las funciones dedicadas a ellas, y guardándolo con sus correspondientes caracteres de escape?

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

De esa manera lo guardarás de forma segura sin tener que perder ningún carácter